JSDoc: Documenting a function with interdependent parameters
I have a function which takes in two parameters, something like:
function example(type, val) {
  // handle "val" based on "type"
}

The acceptable types for val depend on type. The type parameter will always be one of a few select strings. For example, my JSDoc may look something like the following:
/**
 * Handles the value of "val" based on the "type" parameter.
 * @function example
 * @param {"number" | "string" | "boolean"} type - The type of the "val" parameter.
 * @param { ????? } val - The value to handle.
 * @returns {void}
 */
function example(type, val) {
  // handle "val" based on "type"
}

It's worth noting that "number", "string", and "boolean" aren't actually the allowed values of type in my real code; I'm only using them here for demonstration as it makes the problem easier to understand.
As seen in the above code, type can take on a few select values. If type="number", for example, then val should only be allowed to be a number.
I thought I could union a few typedefs together to achieve the result I'm looking for, but I wasn't entirely sure how this would even work as I'm dealing with functions, not objects.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Why do it with just one function? Why not 3 functions, example_number(), example_string(), and example_boolean()?

@Barmar The use case I've shown here isn't my actual use case; I have an event emitter ".on" wrapper that can emit one of a few event types (hence the "type" here); each event type has different callback function parameters (hence the "val" here). Explaining it this way made it easier to understand (minimum required code).

If you're not calling the function directly, jsdoc comments aren't as useful since there's no callers to check.

It's more for the IntelliSense when writing code inside the callback itself. For example: example.on("event", (val) => { /* I want to know the type of "val" here */ }); the type of val is dependent on the "event" string

OK, that makes [Intelli]sense.

Ok. I think now, after some comments I get what you want.
You don't need to make those many @overload JSDoc. Just make sure to document the returned object's on() method.
Here's an example:
/**
 * Handles the value of `value` based on the `type` parameter.
 * 
 * @template { string } TYPE
 * @template { unknown } VALUE
 * 
 * @param { TYPE } type
 * @param { VALUE } value
 * 
 * @returns
 */
function example ( type, value )
{
   // I think you're returning some jQuery object here...
   // But I'm mocking the result:
   const mocked =
   {
      /**
       * @param { string } eventName
       * @param { ( value: VALUE ) => any } callBack
       */
      on: ( eventName, callBack ) =>
      {
         // Handle the event attachment here.
      }
   };
   
   // Note that the result here must be well JSDocumented.
   // If this function returns an GENERIC (`any`) object
   // you'll not `IntelliSense` the `on()` method.
   return mocked;
}


Also, there're more two (+1) examples that could be helpful.
1st case is that you want to produce IntelliSense error if the value is not of the same type as the given in the type parameter. I recommend directly using classes here.
    // 1st case:
    /**
     * Handles the value of `value` only if it matches `type` parameter type.
     * 
     * @template { typeof Boolean | typeof Number | typeof String } TYPE
     * @template { InstanceType < TYPE > } VALUE
     * 
     * @param { TYPE } type - The type of the `value` parameter.
     * @param { VALUE } value - The value to handle.
     * 
     * @returns
     */
    function example ( type, value )
    {
       if ( Object(value) instanceof type )
       {
          // Handle the value...
       }
       
       else
       {
          // Ignore or do something else.
       }
    }

    example(String, 1);
    //--------------^
    // IntelliSense will show an error here if
    // `@ts-check` is enabled (in the first
    // line of the file or in `ts-config.js`,
    // because second parameter type does not
    // match the class in the first parameter.

    example(Number, 1);
    //--------------^
    // IntelliSense will not show an error here
    // if `@ts-check` is enabled (in the first
    // line of the file or in `ts-config.js`,
    // because second parameter type matches
    //.the class in the first parameter.

2nd case is that you want to parse your value differently depending on what type is. Note that in this case (example2) I've kept the type parameter type as string.
    // 2nd case:
    /**
     * Handles the value of `value` based on the `type` parameter.
     * 
     * @param { 'boolean' | 'number' | 'string' } type - The type of the `value` parameter.
     * @param { any } value - The value to handle.
     * 
     * @returns
     */
    function example2 ( type, value )
    {
       switch ( type )
       {
          case 'boolean':
          {
            // Handles value as a boolean.
            break;
          }
          
          case 'number':
          {
            // Handles value as a number.
            break;
          }
          
          case 'string':
          {
            // Handles value as a string.
            break;
          }
          
          default:
          {
            throw new TypeError('Can not parse the value because it does not match the type given.');
            break;
          }
       }
    }

    example2('string', 1);
    // Does not show errors. Will parse `1` as a string.
    
    example2('array', {});
    // Does not show errors. Will throw a TypeError
    // because `array` is not allowed as a type.

3rd case is a suggestion based on the comments.
   // 3rd case:
   /**
    * Handles the value of `value` based on the `type` parameter.
    * 
    * @param { string } type - The type of the `value` parameter.
    * @param { object } value - The value to handle.
    * 
    * @returns
    */
   function example3 ( type, value )
   {
      // I highly recommend using the class in the `type` instead of a string.
      
      if ( Object(value).constructor.name.toLowerCase() == type.toLowerCase()  )
      {
         // Only parses if the value constructor's name is equals to `type`.
      }
      
      else
      {
         // Ignores or do something else.
      }
   }

NOTE: You can actually mix those two approaches.

The second case is more in line with what I want, but I also would like static type checks to function properly. As I mention in my question, I'm not actually using "number", "string", and "boolean", but rather my own custom strings (otherwise there would be no need to pass in a "type" at all); the example I provided was only for demonstration. In other words, I should be able to specify any string (e.g., "foobarbuzz") and have it correspond to a specific val type.

So, value is some object and you want to verify if the object constructor's name matches the type string?

Not exactly; it might help to read the comments Barmar and I posted under the original question. I'm looking for something akin to function overloads, essentially, but in JSDoc.

@simplexshotz See if the edit I made resolves the problem.

Just discovered the @overload tag, which seems to do what I need:
/**
 * Handles the value of "val" based on the "type" parameter.
 * @function example
 * @overload
 * @param {"number"} type - The type of the "val" parameter.
 * @param {number} val - The value to handle.
 * @returns {void}
 */
/**
 * Handles the value of "val" based on the "type" parameter.
 * @function example
 * @overload
 * @param {"string"} type - The type of the "val" parameter.
 * @param {string} val - The value to handle.
 * @returns {void}
 */
/**
 * Handles the value of "val" based on the "type" parameter.
 * @function example
 * @overload
 * @param {"boolean"} type - The type of the "val" parameter.
 * @param {boolean} val - The value to handle.
 * @returns {void}
 */
function example(type, val) {
  // handle "val" based on "type"
}

Not entirely sure why this isn't documented on the JSDoc website, but it seems to work with IntelliSense on VS Code.

See the edit (at the top) of the answer I made for you. There's actually no need for all that JSDoc. You just need to make sure that the return is well documented. If the result on() method is not generated by the function, then you can just replace its documentation. You can still do like you did here though.
